# i don't know how to call a function whose parameter is Node type

Tags: c++, g++, binary-search-tree

I want to call this function in main() but problem is that what parameter I should pass in it while it receives Node type argument
In Simple I just wanna see the height of my tree. So please help me, remove the error which I face during the function call of **height** it needs a Node type parameter and I have no idea what should I pass. Here is the whole code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Binary Search Tree
// 
class Node 
{
    public:
           int data;
           Node *left,*right;
           Node(Node *l=NULL ,int d=0, Node *r=NULL)
           {
            left=l;
            data=d;
            right=r;
           }
};

// Binary Search Tree
class Tree
{
  Node *root;

  public :
      Tree()
      {
        root=NULL;  
      } 

      bool isEmpty()
      {
        if(root==NULL)
          return true;
        else
          return false;  
      }
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //  insert funcation
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      void insert(int val)
      {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            root=new Node(NULL,val,NULL);

        }
        else if(val < root->data && root->left==NULL)
        {
            Node *p=new Node(NULL ,val,NULL);
            root->left=p;
        }   
        else if(val > root->data && root->right==NULL)
        {
            Node *p=new Node (NULL ,val,NULL);
            root->right=p;
        }

        else if(val < root->data)
        insert(val ,root->left);
        else 
        insert(val ,root->right);
      }
      ////////////////////////////////////////
      void insert(int val,Node *n)
      {
         if(val>n->data && n->right==NULL)
         {
           Node *p=new Node(NULL,val,NULL);
           n->right=p;  
         }
         else if(val > n->data)
           insert(val,n->right);
         else if(val <n->data && n->left==NULL)
         {
            Node *p=new Node(NULL,val,NULL);
            n->left=p;
         }
         else
          insert(val,n->left);
      }
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //   pre Order all data display
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      void preOrder(void)
      {
        if(isEmpty())
        cout<<"Tree is Empty\n";
        else
            preOrder(root);
      }
      void preOrder(Node *n)
      {
        if(n!=NULL)
         {
            cout<<n->data<<endl;
            preOrder(n->left);
            preOrder(n->right);
        }
      }
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //         in fix Order all data display
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      void inOrder()
      {
        if(isEmpty())
        cout<<"Tree is Empty\n";
        else
            inOrder(root);
      }
      void inOrder(Node *n)
      {
        if(n!=NULL)
         {
            inOrder(n->left);
            cout<<n->data<<endl;
            inOrder(n->right);
        }
      }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //    post  Order all data display
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      void posOrder()
      {
        if(isEmpty())
        cout<<"Tree is Empty\n";
        else
            posOrder(root);
      }
      void posOrder(Node *n)
      {
        if(n!=NULL)
         {
            posOrder(n->left);
            posOrder(n->right);
            cout<<n->data<<endl;
        }
      } 

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //                    Search funcation
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      void search(int val)
      {
        if(isEmpty())
                   cout<<"Tree is Empty\n";
        else
           search(val,root);
      }
      void search(int v,Node *p)
      {    
           if(v==p->data)
                  cout<<"val : "<<p->data<<endl;        
           else if(v < p->data && p->left!=NULL)
                  search(v,p->left);
           else if(v>p->data && p->right!=NULL)
                search(v,p->right);
           else 
                  cout<<"Data Not Found \n";
      } 

     Node *l;
     int deleteKey(int val)
     {
      if(isEmpty())
      cout<<"Tree is Empty\n";
      else if(root->data==val &&(root->left==NULL&&root->right==NULL))
      {
         int temp=root->data;
         delete root;
         return temp;   
      }
       else
        deleteKey(val,root);
      }

       int deleteKey(int v,Node *p)
      {  
           if(v == p->data)  
             {

                  if(p->left==NULL && p->right==NULL)
                  {
                    if(l->right==p)  
                    {
                      int temp=p->data;
                      delete p;
                      l->right=NULL;
                      return temp;
                    }
                     else 
                     {
                      int temp=p->data;
                      delete p;
                      l->left=NULL;
                      return temp;
                     }
                  }
                  else if(p->right!=NULL) 
                  {
                      int temp=p->data;
                     deleteKey(p,p->right);
                     return temp;
                  }
                  else  
                  {
                    int temp=p->data;
                        cout<<"Left : "<<p->data<<endl;
                    deleteKey(p,p->left,v);
                    return temp;
                  }
             }
           else if(v < p->data && p->left!=NULL)
           {
                  l=p;
                  deleteKey(v,p->left);
           }
           else if(v>p->data &&p->right!=NULL)
           {    
                  l=p; 
                deleteKey(v,p->right);
           }
           else 
                  cout<<"Data Not Found ----\n";
      }

       int deleteKey(Node *find ,Node *next)
      {
            if( next->left == NULL && next->right != NULL ) 
            {
                find->data = next->data;
                deleteKey(find->right , next->right);
            }
            else if( next->left == NULL&& next->right==NULL)
            {
                find->data = next->data;
                delete next;
                find->right=NULL;
            }
            else  
            {
                Node *q;
                while(next->left!=NULL)
                {
                   q=next;  
                   next=next->left;
                 }
                 find->data=next->data;
                 delete next;
                 q->left=NULL;  
             }
      }
          int deleteKey(Node* find,Node *next,int v)
      {
            if( next->right == NULL && next->left != NULL ) 
            {
                find->data = next->data;
                deleteKey(find->left , next->left,v);
            }
            else if( next->right == NULL&& next->left==NULL)
            {
                find->data = next->data;
                delete next;
                find->left=NULL;
            }
            else 
            {
                Node *q;
                while(next->right!=NULL)
                {
                   q=next;  
                   next=next->right;
                 }
                 find->data=next->data;
                 delete next;
                 q->right=NULL; 
             }
      }

       ~Tree()
       {
         dist();
       }

             void dist()
             {
                dist(root);
             }
              void dist(Node *n)
              {
                if(n!=NULL)
                {
                     dist(n->left);
                     dist(n->right);
                     delete n;
               }
             }
             int height(Node *root)
             {
                int h=0;
                if (isEmpty())
                {
                    cout<<"Tree is Empty\n";    
                }
                else
                {
                    int left_height=height(root->left);
                    int right_height=height(root->right);
                    h=1+max(left_height, right_height);

                }
                return h;
             }

};

int main()
{
    Tree obj;
    obj.height();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to pass, root of your tree in this function, but the better approach will be if you make one more function without any parameter and make that function public and call your this private function from it by passing this->root;

Here you can see :

```
public:
int getHeight()
{
return height(this->root); //pass your Tree class root
}
```

and make that function private in class , for efficiency.

```
private:
int height(Node *root)
             {
                int h=0;
                if (isEmpty())
                {
                    cout<<"Tree is Empty\n";    
                }
                else
                {
                    int left_height=height(root->left);
                    int right_height=height(root->right);
                    h=1+max(left_height, right_height);

                }
                return h;
             }
```

Another, approach is to make a getRoot() function in class and get Root of Tree class in main and pass to height function. But The first approach will be better.

Comment: Sir i am calling this function in int main like this
obj.height(--);
What should i pass in parenthesis?
Thanks

Comment: Assuming there is such a class called `Tree` (the OP made no such claim), this would be a good path to take. If the OP has no such class, then the answer is to simply pass whatever `Node *` is rooting the tree.  Unrelated, the node pointer parameter should ideally be `const`. Nothing is changed, so make sure it says that way.

Comment: @MaharAsifLak is `obj` an instance of your "tree" class, hosting your tree `root` pointer? If so, then this answer is *perfect*.

Comment: @MaharAsifLak can you post your class  ? So I can teach you better. Or tell me how and where you are using this function ?

Comment: class Node 
{
 public:
     int data;
     Node *left,*right;
     Node(Node *l=NULL ,int d=0, Node *r=NULL)
     {
      left=l;
      data=d;
      right=r;
     }
};

Comment: @MaharAsifLak if you'll edit your post with your full code it'll be better.

Comment: Sir i edit it
I just wana get the height of  tree Thanks

Comment: @MaharAsifLak the first solution is right, you just have to make function for height which do not take a parameter and call your original height function in it/

Comment: It works But now when i execute it a dialog box appear with error tree.cpp stop working but if i exclude getheight function it run.

Comment: Can you describe your error if its still not working ? @MaharAsifLak